# jQuery validation plugin validating html control only

Tags: jquery, html, validation, controls

I'm developing a form with client side validation using jQuery validation plugin.

This almost works perfect but i'm getting a problem:

The form is composed by 5 inputs.
One input requires the content of other input(that must be valid) to proceed the validation, i  show one example:

```
$('#submitionData').validate(
    {
                rules: {
                    tb_valorEmprestimo:
                    {
                        required: true,
                        min: 1000,
                        max: 999999999,
                        checkForTranche: true

...


jQuery.validator.addMethod("checkForTranche", function()
    {
        return $('#tb_tranche').valid() == 1 ? true : false
    }
, "Please Correct Tranche field");
```

Where #tb_tranche is the control i need to validate first, but one problem ocurrors,
When the tb_tranche is valid the text saying ...Please Correct Tranche field continues appeearing in the tb_valorEmprestimo input..

Apreciate help guys, thanks